# compiling c++ applications so they can work on other computers as well

Tags: c++, deployment, gcc, compilation, sdl

So I have this very simply SDL application I want to be able to pass to my friend without having him download a whole bunch of SDL packages.

how can I go about this? I was told to use this line to compile:
(note that I use ubuntu linux and so does my friend, and that this application compiles and runs without the  "-Wl,-Bstatic" options just fine.)

```
    g++ test-sdl.cpp -o test-sdl -Wl,-Bstatic -lSDL_image -lSDL
```

But then I get this error:

```
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s  
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

why am I getting this error? how do I fix it? do I even have to do this in this way? Is there a different/easier/alternative way?

Am I asking for so much by wanting to save my friend the hassle of downloading packages he will probably never use anyway?

Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion, SDL does not qualify as a package he will probably never use anyway.  Unless he never uses programs that involve graphics (e.g. games), SDL is something he'll probably find himself hitting later.

Comment: That's assuming way too much about an end user.

Comment: you are missing the point. it's an SDL package today, it could be anything else tomorrow. I will not deploy an app assuming anything about a user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the long run your best bet would be to figure out how to build .debs and then your friend's system's package management can take care of installing all the dependencies needed.  If you want to distribute the packages more widely, using the platform's native packaging system as intended will save you and your users a lot of headaches.

Take a look at Ubuntu's guide to [packaging](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete) and [pbuilder](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PbuilderHowto).

Personally, I learned how to do this for my own projects (on Debian) from the Martin Krafft [Debian book](http://debiansystem.info/), and find using [yada](http://yada.alioth.debian.org/) streamlines the process considerably.

Comment: hmm it would seem this is a more logical alternative. By having me install the debs for him through my own deb. Is there a way for me to determine exactly which packages are necessary (in order to install the least amount of packages necessary to get the app running)

Comment: Yes look at the man page for dpkg-depcheck - you should be able to use it on your app to get a list of all the packages your app is dependent on when it runs.  (I've seen other methods involving processing strace output too).

Answer (score 2):

You should get rid of the -B, I think (this changes the search path, see man g++, and thus you can't find your libraries anymore).

The switch you meant is -static, without the B.

Edit in response to comments: sorry, that was incomplete. Instead, replace all of "-Wl,-Bstatic" with just "-static".

As codelogic wrote, -static is not an option to the linker (which -Wl implies).

Comment: this:
    g++ test-sdl3.cpp -o test-sdl3 -Wl,-static -lSDL_image -lSDL
does not work either. It returns the same error.

Comment: -static is not a linker option, it's a gcc option.

Comment: this: g++ -static test-sdl3.cpp -o test-sdl3 -Wl,-lSDL_image -lSDL
and this: g++ -static test-sdl3.cpp -o test-sdl3 -lSDL_image -lSDL

return an identical stack of errors so big my terminal does not remember enough lines for me to see the first error output.